# Problem with 'or' in 'day.weekday() == 5 or 6'

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

Why does using the 'or' operator give different results in this case? Why must I write the day.weekday() twice rather than just == 5 or 6

---

This is the option that works

```
if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
```

This is the option that gives a different result

```
if day.weekday() == 5 or 6:
```

Answer (score 1):

Or statements work as such:

```py
if (condition) or (condition):
```

By saying:

```py
if day.weekday() == 5 or 6:
```

The code thinks that you are implying that 6 is a condition, which if you are trying to print something if it's a Saturday (since saturday is the 6th day of the week), you won't get anything printed. Hope this helps, leave a comment if it doesn't, or you need additional help.

Answer (score 1):

It gives a different result because "day.weekday() == 5" and "6" are being evaluated separately. It doesn't give you an error because any number that is not 0 evaluates to "True".

The better way to write this would be:

```
if day.weekday() in (5, 6):
```

Comment: what is the 6 being evaluated as?

Comment: basically the 6 is just being converted to a boolean. Any number that is 0 will be False. Any number that is not 0 will be True. So that's why if you want to check multiple values you have to use in. Putting the 5 and 6 in parentheses puts it in a tuple so calling in checks if the value of day.weekday() is in the tuple.

Comment: No problem, glad to help